# Unity iOS Build linker error

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, build, linker-errors

I am using unity for developing my iOS game I am stuck on the following error. I tried to search StackOverflow and googled too but could not see any post to solve my problem. I am using google ads, google play services, Facebook integration.
I have this my pod file

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'Unity-iPhone' do

pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

pod 'GooglePlayGames'

pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'

end

target 'Unity-iPhone Tests' do

pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

pod 'GooglePlayGames'

pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

I have following linker errors in XCode, not sure which framework I am missing

Showing Recent Messages

> "_VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailableResponse_Dispose", referenced from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailableResponse_Dispose_m3414435646
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailableResponse_Dispose_m3414435646)
>   "_VideoManager_GetCaptureStateResponse_GetVideocapturestate",
>   referenced from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureStateResponse_GetVideocapturestate_m3223155740 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureStateResponse_GetVideocapturestate_m3223155740)
>   "_VideoManager_GetCaptureStateResponse_GetStatus", referenced from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureStateResponse_GetStatus_m780417724
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureStateResponse_GetStatus_m780417724)
>   "_VideoManager_GetCaptureStateResponse_Dispose", referenced from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureStateResponse_Dispose_m3090785104 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureStateResponse_Dispose_m3090785104)
>   "_VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilitiesResponse_Dispose", referenced
>   from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilitiesResponse_Dispose_m3101756481
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilitiesResponse_Dispose_m3101756481)
>   "_VideoManager_RegisterCaptureOverlayStateChangedListener", referenced
>   from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_RegisterCaptureOverlayStateChangedListener_m944800198
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_RegisterCaptureOverlayStateChangedListener_m3446186028, _VideoManager_VideoManager_RegisterCaptureOverlayStateChangedListener_m944800198
>   )   "_VideoManager_IsCaptureSupported", referenced from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_IsCaptureSupported_m392793648 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_IsCaptureSupported_m1920993052, _VideoManager_VideoManager_IsCaptureSupported_m392793648 )   "_VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailable", referenced from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailable_m924375812 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailable_m1846214581_MetadataUsageId, _VideoManager_VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailableResponse_Dispose_m3414435646
>   ,
>   _VideoManager_VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailableResponse_GetStatus_m675688352
>   , _VideoManager_VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailable_m924375812 ,
>   _VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailable_m1846214581 , _VideoManager_VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailableResponse_GetIscaptureavailable_m1300145164
>   )   "_VideoManager_UnregisterCaptureOverlayStateChangedListener",
>   referenced from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_UnregisterCaptureOverlayStateChangedListener_m798576001
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_UnregisterCaptureOverlayStateChangedListener_m1920474941,
>   _VideoManager_VideoManager_UnregisterCaptureOverlayStateChangedListener_m798576001
>   )   "_VideoCaptureState_CaptureMode", referenced from:
>         _VideoCaptureState_VideoCaptureState_CaptureMode_m331686759 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoCaptureState_VideoCaptureState_CaptureMode_m331686759)   "_VideoManager_GetCaptureState", referenced from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureState_m3579154397 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureStateResponse_GetVideocapturestate_m3223155740,
>   _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureStateResponse_GetStatus_m780417724
>   , _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureState_m3579154397 ,
>   _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureStateResponse_Dispose_m3090785104 , _VideoManager_GetCaptureState_m1761254752_MetadataUsageId ,
>   _VideoManager_GetCaptureState_m1761254752 )   "_VideoManager_ShowCaptureOverlay", referenced from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_ShowCaptureOverlay_m2996364919 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_ShowCaptureOverlay_m2288358931, _VideoManager_VideoManager_ShowCaptureOverlay_m2996364919 )   "_VideoCaptureState_Valid", referenced from:
>         _VideoCaptureState_VideoCaptureState_Valid_m2629445250 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoCaptureState_VideoCaptureState_Valid_m2629445250)   "_VideoCapabilities_IsMicSupported", referenced from:
>         _VideoCapabilities_VideoCapabilities_IsMicSupported_m1112922381 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoCapabilities_VideoCapabilities_IsMicSupported_m1112922381)   "_VideoCaptureState_IsPaused", referenced from:
>         _VideoCaptureState_VideoCaptureState_IsPaused_m3440800726 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoCaptureState_VideoCaptureState_IsPaused_m3440800726)   "_VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailableResponse_GetIscaptureavailable",
>   referenced from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailableResponse_GetIscaptureavailable_m1300145164
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailableResponse_GetIscaptureavailable_m1300145164)
>   "_VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilities", referenced from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilities_m552067333 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilitiesResponse_GetVideocapabilities_m4093813970,
>   _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilitiesResponse_GetStatus_m1769470309
>   ,
>   _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilitiesResponse_Dispose_m3101756481
>   , _VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilities_m1740537508_MetadataUsageId ,
>   _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilities_m552067333 , _VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilities_m1740537508 )   "_VideoCaptureState_IsOverlayVisible", referenced from:
>         _VideoCaptureState_VideoCaptureState_IsOverlayVisible_m1896624058 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoCaptureState_VideoCaptureState_IsOverlayVisible_m1896624058)   "_VideoCaptureState_IsCapturing", referenced from:
>         _VideoCaptureState_VideoCaptureState_IsCapturing_m510887465 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoCaptureState_VideoCaptureState_IsCapturing_m510887465)   "_VideoCapabilities_IsCameraSupported", referenced from:
>         _VideoCapabilities_VideoCapabilities_IsCameraSupported_m1491641367 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoCapabilities_VideoCapabilities_IsCameraSupported_m1491641367)   "_GameServices_Builder_SetShowConnectingPopup", referenced from:
>         _Builder_GameServices_Builder_SetShowConnectingPopup_m2755817575 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Builder_GameServices_Builder_SetShowConnectingPopup_m2755817575)   "_VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailableResponse_GetStatus", referenced from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailableResponse_GetStatus_m675688352
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_VideoManager_IsCaptureAvailableResponse_GetStatus_m675688352)
>   "_VideoCapabilities_Valid", referenced from:
>         _VideoCapabilities_VideoCapabilities_Valid_m3674486668 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoCapabilities_VideoCapabilities_Valid_m3674486668)   "_VideoCapabilities_Dispose", referenced from:
>         _VideoCapabilities_VideoCapabilities_Dispose_m3423006733 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoCapabilities_VideoCapabilities_Dispose_m3423006733)   "_VideoCapabilities_SupportsQualityLevel", referenced from:
>         _VideoCapabilities_VideoCapabilities_SupportsQualityLevel_m4105731366 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoCapabilities_VideoCapabilities_SupportsQualityLevel_m4105731366, _VideoCapabilities_SupportsQualityLevel_m1988298174 , _VideoCapabilities_SupportsQualityLevel_m1988298174_MetadataUsageId )   "_VideoCapabilities_IsWriteStorageSupported", referenced from:
>         _VideoCapabilities_VideoCapabilities_IsWriteStorageSupported_m1435984560
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoCapabilities_VideoCapabilities_IsWriteStorageSupported_m1435984560)
>   "_VideoCaptureState_Dispose", referenced from:
>         _VideoCaptureState_VideoCaptureState_Dispose_m158234657 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoCaptureState_VideoCaptureState_Dispose_m158234657)   "_VideoCaptureState_QualityLevel", referenced from:
>         _VideoCaptureState_VideoCaptureState_QualityLevel_m1216797939 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoCaptureState_VideoCaptureState_QualityLevel_m1216797939)   "_VideoCapabilities_SupportsCaptureMode", referenced from:
>         _VideoCapabilities_VideoCapabilities_SupportsCaptureMode_m1774432526 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoCapabilities_SupportsCaptureMode_m625125118_MetadataUsageId, _VideoCapabilities_SupportsCaptureMode_m625125118 , _VideoCapabilities_VideoCapabilities_SupportsCaptureMode_m1774432526 )   "_VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilitiesResponse_GetVideocapabilities",
>   referenced from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilitiesResponse_GetVideocapabilities_m4093813970
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilitiesResponse_GetVideocapabilities_m4093813970)
>   "_VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilitiesResponse_GetStatus", referenced
>   from:
>         _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilitiesResponse_GetStatus_m1769470309
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _VideoManager_VideoManager_GetCaptureCapabilitiesResponse_GetStatus_m1769470309)
>   "_CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_Dispose", referenced from:
>         _CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_Dispose_m967314825
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_Dispose_m967314825)
>   "_CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_SetOnCaptureOverlayStateChangedCallback",
>   referenced from:
>         _CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_SetOnCaptureOverlayStateChangedCallback_m1064033775
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_SetOnCaptureOverlayStateChangedCallback_m1064033775,
>   _CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_SetOnCaptureOverlayStateChangedCallback_m2915082994
>   ,
>   _CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_SetOnCaptureOverlayStateChangedCallback_m2915082994_MetadataUsageId
>   )   "_CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_Construct", referenced from:
>         _CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_Construct_m2359152431
>   in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.o
>        (maybe you meant: _CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_CaptureOverlayStateListenerHelper_Construct_m2359152431)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Still not resolved. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem, Here is what I did

I removed GooglePlayGames folder from my unity project and downgraded the google play services package to GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.36.unitypackage.
after that it build successfully with no errors.